# Is the speed of light exactly 299792458 m/s?

Tags: speed-of-light, definition, conventions, si-units, metrology

Is there is any uncertainty in the measurement of the speed of light?

Comment: The very first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) answers your question.

Comment: My dad was a buyer for Apollo components.

He told me back in the 1960's (or very early 1970's), that the speed of light was 186,282.3960−mile/second with a tolerance of ±3.6−feet/second.

Even then, the tolerance seemed like it should have had the same units as the average stated value.

However, if the tolerance was mi/s, then the excessive digits in the main value were extraneous.The stated tolerance works out to about ±0.0007−mi/s.

With the SI value of 299,792,458−m/s, the tolleranced value shown above corresponds closely as (299,792,456.31 +/- 1.13)−m/s (an error of 0.56-m/s).

Comment: There are three different things. One, the *defined* value of the constant *c*. Second, the *real* speed of light , as close at is can measured. Three, the limit speed that arises from special relativity and is *assumed*, for several reasons, to be equal to the speed of traveling photons.

Answer (score 8):

See page 131 of the [SI brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure):

> The metre, symbol $\mathrm m$, is the SI unit of length. It is defined by taking the fixed numerical value of the speed of light in vacuum, $c$, to be $299\, 792\, 458$ when expressed in the unit $\mathrm m\mathrm s^{−1}$, where the second is defined in terms of the caesium frequency $\Delta\nu_{Cs}$.
>
> **This definition implies the exact relation $c = 299\, 792\, 458\mathrm m\mathrm s^{−1}$.**

(Emphasis mine)